# checkbox in html JavaScript that remain checked even on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to create a simple html-javascript checklist that when a user check a particular list it remain checked for them even if they reload the page. Here is a demo which on reload is again all list are unchecked. http://jsfiddle.net/mAnUQ/

But I want the website to store the checked fields even if user reload the webpage.

```js
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
  var exdate = new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function set_check(me) {
  setCookie(me.value, me.checked, 60 * 60 * 1);
  console.log(me.value);
  console.log(me.checked);
  console.log(document.cookie)
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I will upload new Image" onChange="set_check(this)">
    <label for="check1">I will upload new Image</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I approve this sample for a Night Light" onChange="set_check(this)">
    <label for="check2">I approve this sample for a Night Light</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="proceed_opt[]" value="Select One" onChange="set_check(this)">
    <label for="check3">Select One</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="proceed_opt[]" value="other" onChange="set_check(this)">
    <label for="check4">Other See comments</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to persist your data in a cookie.  Is your code failing in some way?  What isn't working?

Comment: When I reload the page, all the boxes are unchecked even if I  "checked" them.

Comment: Where is the code for setting the state of the boxes when the page loads?  Basically, you're writing to a cookie, but where are you *reading from* that cookie?

Comment: I am totally new to this, and this is what I got from searching it online from a tutorial there was no other code.

Comment: Then I guess it's not that your code isn't working, it's that it's simply incomplete and you need to keep going.  At a high level, what you'd be looking to do is check for the existence of your cookie when the page loads.  If it exists, read the data from it and use that data to pre-check the checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you I will look more into it.